# How to read double value with semicolon between instead of a dot

Tags: c

I have these time duration values such as 1:23, 2:45(2 minutes 45 seconds). And i want to read these values from a file into the duration field of a song struct as 1.23 and 2.45. Is there an easy way to do it or i have to just change semicolon to dot and convert it to a double? (It will be in C)

Comment: Before you do, can you confirm that you want `1.23`, and not `1.38333333333`  i.e.: `1 + 23/60`?

Comment: Yes, changing the semicolon to a dot is the path of least resistance. Although the entire concept of expressing time as a double value is weird, and is destined to create various problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 minute and 23 seconds is not the same as 1.23 minutes.

One way to do this:

```
int min, sec;
double dur = -1.0; // initialize to an invalid duration

if ( scanf( "%d:%d", &min, &sec ) == 2 )
{
  dur = min + sec/60.0;
}
else
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Invalid duration, try again\n" );
  while ( getchar() != '\n' ) // clear out the input stream
    ; // empty loop
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And, what if i wanted to store 2:23 as an int value such as 223. how would the scan function be?

Comment: Replace the contents of the if clause with:
`dur = min*100 + sec; `

Comment: @BarışHazar The scan function would be the same, but what you do with the `min` and `sec` values afterwards would differ.

Comment: @BarışHazar: If you want the total number of seconds, you'd read things the same way, but calculate `dur` as `min * 60 + sec`.  Remember a minute is not 100 seconds, so `2:23` is not 223 seconds, it's 143 seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to store the integer `223` in that case. That would be saying you have two-hundred twenty three... what? For times, you almost certainly want to store an integer number of the smallest applicable unit: two minutes and twenty-three seconds is 143 seconds, and two hours and twenty-three minutes would be 143 minutes or 8580 seconds.